# Resizing items with a media query not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm building an application that have to work on "small" screens (1024*768) or higher resolution screen.

I have in the application a page that have some items presented in two columns. But on "small" screens, the width of the items is too large to keep a good layout, so I want to reduce the number of columns to one. The columns are build with a `<ul>` containing `<li>` with `float:left` attribute (this is actually a jQuery Sortable plugin output).

My behavior of the page is to allow users to drag and drop items between a "source" list and "target" list in order to select items (this is working and if it can help, I can paste the code).

To solve this issue, I have tried to set up a media query.

In my css file I have :

```
.sourceItems, .targetItems {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.sourceItems {
    width: 530px;
}

.targetItems {
    width: 280px;
}

    .sourceItems li, .targetItems li {
        border: solid 1px black;
        float: left;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 4px;
        width: 220px;
        min-height: 10px;
        cursor: move;
        background-image: url('/_layouts/images/personresult.gif') !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        padding-left: 20px;
        background-color: #DFEFFC;
        background-position: left center !important;
    }

        .sourceItems li.user, .targetItems li.user {
        }

        .sourceItems li.entity, .targetItems li.entity {
            background-position: left center;
            border: solid 1px black;
            float: left;
            margin: 4px;
            padding: 4px;
            width: 200px;
            background-image: url('/_layouts/images/peopletitle.png') !important;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            height: 50px;
            cursor: move;
            padding-left: 40px;
            background-color: #CCFF99;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

@media screen and (max-width: 1024) {
    .sourceItems {
        width: 200px;
    }

    .targetItems {
        width: 200px;
    }

        .sourceItems li, .targetItems li {
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 2px;
            width: 180px;
            min-height: 10px;
            background-image: url('/_layouts/images/personresult.gif') !important;
            -moz-background-size: 50%;
            -o-background-size: 50%;
            -webkit-background-size: 50%;
            background-size: 50%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            padding-left: 10px;
            font-size: 1.1em;
        }

            .sourceItems li.user, .targetItems li.user {
            }

            .sourceItems li.entity, .targetItems li.entity {
                -moz-background-size: 50%;
                -o-background-size: 50%;
                -webkit-background-size: 50%;
                background-size: 50%;
                margin: 2px;
                padding: 2px;
                width: 180px;
                background-image: url('/_layouts/images/peopletitle.png') !important;
                font-size: 1.1em;
                height: 30px;
                padding-left: 20px;
            }
}
```

However, this makes not difference when the page load (the element is always two columns large).

Don't know if it can help, but here is the dump of the DOM (from the IE developer tools) :

```
<UL class="sourceItems droptrue ui-sortable" jQuery172019945692622544986="151">
  <LI class="ui-state-default entity" jQuery172019945692622544986="75">some item 1</LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default entity" jQuery172019945692622544986="76">some item 2</LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default entity" jQuery172019945692622544986="77">some item 3</LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default entity" jQuery172019945692622544986="78">some item 4</LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default entity" jQuery172019945692622544986="79">some item 5</LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default entity" jQuery172019945692622544986="80">some item 6</LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default entity" jQuery172019945692622544986="81">some item 7</LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default entity" jQuery172019945692622544986="82">some item 8</LI>
</UL>
<UL class="targetItems droptrue ui-sortable" jQuery172024919617247411335="152"></UL>
```

Here is a screenshot of the output with a "large screen":

[image: On a large screen]

Here is a screenshot of the output with a "small screen":

[image: On a small screen]

Here is a screenshot of the **desired** output on a "small screen" (tweaked the dom using IE dev tools to produce the screenshot:

[image: Desired result]

I'd appreciate any help that may help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing length prefix `px/cm/in` in

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024) {
                              ^^^^ // Missing px
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/hVjje/) - (Not Working)

It should be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
                                  ^^ // Added px
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/3SnFL/) - (Working)

[**SEE REFERENCE**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width)

Comment: I see this is working in your sample, but it does not in my app. I have some question: **1.** If define a rule (max-width), do I have to also define the (min-width)? Or does it handle kind of default style, overriden by a custom rule. **2.** I put my `@media` rule within a css file. Is it allowed to put a @media rule in the same level that classical css rules? Or do I have to create a dedicated css file with my `@media` rule? **3.** I'm not sure on which element the width rules apply. Do it apply to the screen dimension or the element dimension ?

Comment: Ok, I figured out why this didn't workd. My application outputs a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` which makes IE 9 render using IE 8 engine. And IE 8 does not supports media queries, so my query is ignored. I'll see if I can change this in the app, but it's out of scope of this question. Anyways, thanks for your answer. It is actually part of the solution